# Hexagonal binning with exponential random numbers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been following the block that uses hexagonal binning of random points with the normal distribution but instead trying to tailor it to the exponential distribution.

The code runs, but the output seems to show a mirror along the x-axis. That is, the points are all clustered along the upper-left instead of lower-left. I've been playing with the transform function but can't quite get it. What am I missing? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2mpfLb0/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.hexagon {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var randomX = d3.randomExponential(1 / 30),
    randomY = d3.randomExponential(1 / 30),
    points = d3.range(2000).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });

var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "steelblue"))
    .domain([0, 20]);

var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
    .radius(5)
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);

g.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "hexagon")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }) 
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your scales, but you never use them:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
})
```

**Solution**: use your scales:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
    //scales here --------^--------------^
})
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var randomX = d3.randomExponential(1 / 30),
  randomY = d3.randomExponential(1 / 30),
  points = d3.range(2000).map(function() {
    return [randomX(), randomY()];
  });

var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "steelblue"))
  .domain([0, 20]);

var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
  .radius(5)
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ]);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, width])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, height])
  .range([height, 0]);

g.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "hexagon")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.length);
  });
```

```css
.hexagon {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Gerardo! It's displaying as intended now.

Comment: No worries. Here is an advice: use meaningful names for the variables, like `xScale` and `yScale`, not `x` and `y`. Using meaningful names helps when it comes to situations like that: you can easily see that you forgot something...